# How can I find the right name for a package to be installed

Tags: linux-mint

I'm trying to install Nomachine on my Linux Mint computer.The installation instructions tell me to:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i <pkgVersion>_<arch>.deb
```

However I have no idea on what I should fill inside the brackets. I have had the same exact problem with other packages too. Is there some list where I can find the exact name of the package I want to install (in this case Nomachine)?

Answer (score 0):

I get it now:
DPKG is for installing packages that have already been downloaded. So the right name can be found inside the download folder.